How to Add Room Library to a Compose Desktop App Created with IntelliJ IDEA Built-in Wizard?
I'm making a Compose Desktop app using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. I started the project with the built-in wizard (not the web version). I'm having trouble finding clear instructions on how to set up the Room library for a desktop app.
Most tutorials I find are about Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) and use the web-based wizard, which is different from the built-in IntelliJ IDEA wizard.
Can someone give me a simple guide or resources on how to add Room to a Compose Desktop project made with the built-in wizard in IntelliJ IDEA?
Here is my initial build.gradle.kts file:
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose")
}

group = "org.abdo"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    // Note, if you develop a library, you should use compose.desktop.common.
    // compose.desktop.currentOs should be used in launcher-sourceSet
    // (in a separate module for demo project and in testMain).
    // With compose.desktop.common you will also lose @Preview functionality
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "demo2"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}

Thanks!

Did you mean the Android Jetpack Room Library.
I had try to set up it with kmm recently.
Maybe it can help you...
In my build.gradle

First apply androidx-room plugin and ksp plugin in my build.gradle,

Secondly, implementation androidx-room and androidx-sqlite-bundled in my dependencies.

add androidx-room-compiler to ksp

set up room schema directory
maybe like this:
plugins{
    id("androidx.room").version("roomVersion")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp").version("kspVersion")
    //other plugins
}
dependencies{
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.sqlite:sqlite-bundled:sqliteVersion")
add("kspJvm","androidx.room:room-compiler:roomVersion")
    //other implementation
}
room{
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    schemaDirectory("debug","$projectDir/schemas/debug")
    schemaDirectory("release","$projectDir/schemas/release")
}



Than create Database classes, DAO, Entity classes as usual.
@Database(
    entities = [
        XXEntity::class
    ],
    version = 1
)
@ConstructedBy(XXXDatabaseConstructor::class)
abstract class XXXDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun dao():XXXDAO 
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "xxxx"
)
data class XXEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val primaryKey:Long,
    val someValue
){
    
}
@Dao
interface XXXDAO {
   //inserts, updates, .....
}

Create a expect object XXXDatabaseConstructor extends RoomDatabaseConstructor. The Room Compiler will help me generate the actual class.
@Suppress("EXPECT_ACTUAL_CLASSIFIERS_ARE_IN_BETA_WARNING")
expect object XXXDatabaseConstructor:RoomDatabaseConstructor<XXXDatabase> {

}

fun getDatabaseBuilder(): RoomDatabase.Builder<XXXDatabase> {
    val dbFile = File( "sqlite.db")
    return Room.databaseBuilder<XXXDatabase>(
        name = dbFile.absolutePath,
    )
}
fun getXXXDatabase(
    builder: RoomDatabase.Builder<XXXDatabase>
): LogHistoryDatabase {
    return builder
//    .addMigrations(MIGRATIONS)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade(true)
    .setDriver(BundledSQLiteDriver())
    .setQueryCoroutineContext(Dispatchers.IO)
    .build()
}

Some useful links:
Androidx Room User Guide
Migrade to kmm
How to set up room multiplatform

Thanks for your answer! I tried it, but it didn't work. I'm looking for a way to do this with compose desktop in the gradle file generated by Intellij, not the KMP way

I got understood what you are saying .
I have a similar question recently and I found its easy to solve it.
Just simply follow the Android Developers Rooms Official Instructions, than it will automatically generate the codes like it's done on android target.
// your build.gradle.kts may be like:
plugins {
    alias(kotlinx.plugins.jvm)
    alias(kotlinx.plugins.google.ksp)
    alias(androidx.plugins.room)
}
dependencies {
    implementation(androidx.room.runtime)
    implementation(androidx.sqlite.bundled)
    ksp(androidx.room.compiler)
}
room {
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    schemaDirectory("debug", "$projectDir/schemas/debug")
    schemaDirectory("release", "$projectDir/schemas/release")
}

//database.kt

@Database(
    version = 1,
    entities = [
        SomeEntity::class,
    ]
)
//@TypeConverters(Convertors::class)
abstract class SomeDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun dao():DAO
}

//dao
@Dao
interface DAO{
    some queries/inserts/deletes
}

//entity
@Entity
data class SomeEntity(
    val some:String
)

than you can use your database like:
val database=Room
    .databaseBuilder<JobsDatabase>("database path")
    .setDriver(BundledSQLiteDriver())
    .setQueryCoroutineContext(Dispatchers.IO)
    .build()
database.dao().insertSomething()
database.dao().querySomething()

Than build.
It will generate the code you want.

